# How to give value in runtime for chef

Tags: chef, apache-httpd

I got stuck with a scenario where I need to provide runtime value while restarting/starting `httpd` service using Chef.

I installed SSL certs where it asks password for every reload or start. I tried giving:

```
service 'httpd' do
  supports restart: true, reload: false, status: true
  options "password"
end
```

But I don't have any luck.

Any help about how to pass this value while `httpd` restarts using Chef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't. Instead you should use proper secrets management system that would provide you unlocked SSL certificate.

---

By secret management I mean tooling like [k8s secret management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) or [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io).

You can read [Medium post about secrets](https://medium.com/on-docker/secrets-and-lie-abilities-the-state-of-modern-secret-management-2017-c82ec9136a3d).

Comment: Maybe you could elucidate what proper secrets management means to you.

Comment: @Lukasz we need to have SSL certificates to maintain our security.

Comment: @pandey I am not saying that you should resign from SSL but from the fact that your certificate need password. This is the problem.

Comment: Yes right, so can we provide this password while reloading. A httpd

Comment: The point of my post is that there should be no password at all. Instead your httpd server should have access to the certificate as is, without any additional information. [Here you can find how](https://serverfault.com/questions/160768/stop-apache-from-asking-for-ssl-password-each-restart)

Comment: Yeah I just took out the password for pem key to get my httpd service get run with out password. One other way I tried is like SSLPassPhraseDialog which needs to be placed in httpd.conf file as you mentioned in above comment